# Why is my code not deleting the duplicate nodes? My output is still 12311

Tags: java, linked-list, void

I am trying to delete duplicate nodes in an unsorted linked list. However, my output is not changing the linked list at all.

I tried to replace this code:

```
            list.add(new Node(1));
    list.add(new Node(2));
    list.add(new Node(3));
    list.add(new Node(1));
    list.add(new Node(1));
```

with

```
            Node firstNode = new Node(1);
            Node secondNode = new Node(2);
            Node thirdNode = new Node(3);
            Node fourthNode = new Node(1);
            Node fifthNode = new Node(1);

            firstNode.next = secondNode;
            secondNode.next = thirdNode;
            thirdNode.next = fourthNode;
            fourthNode.next = fifthNode;

            list.add(firstNode);
    list.add(secondNode);
    list.add(thirdNode);
    list.add(fourthNode);
    list.add(fifthNode);
```

but still no luck.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Node {

  public int value;
  public Node next;

  public Node(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }  
}

class LinkedLists {

  Node head;

  public static void removeDups(Node n) {

    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Node prev = null;

    if (n == null) {
        return;
    }

    while(n != null) {

        if (set.contains(n.value)) {
            prev.next = n.next;
        } else {
            set.add(n.value);
            prev = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }           
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Node> list = new LinkedList<Node>();

    list.add(new Node(1));
    list.add(new Node(2));
    list.add(new Node(3));
    list.add(new Node(1));
    list.add(new Node(1));

    removeDups(list.getFirst());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i).value);
    }

}

}
```

I expect an output of 123.

Comment: This is not how you implement LinkedList. If it is home-work then i'm sure that you are asked to implement a linkedlist by yourself and not to use from Java's lib.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confused between implementing the Linked List yourself and using Java's own `LinkedList` collection.

Java's [`java.util.LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) manages the `next` and `previous` pointers internally. It does not allow you to manipulate them, or expect you to manage them. It implements a doubly-linked list, but that is abstracted from you.

You are adding 5 nodes to this `LinkedList`, and nowhere are you [removing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) the duplicates.

Your `Node` class in this case is useless. You are updating a separate linked chain of `next` pointers, but you are not traversing it or using this in any way.

You could have simply added the numbers directly to the `LinkedList`, and removed the duplicates afterwards:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(1);
list.add(1);

List<Integer> uniqueList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.print(list.get(i).value);
}
```